# Remove attributes from product links in cart (Woocommerce - get_permalink)

Tags: wordpress, attributes, woocommerce, permalinks, cart

Echoing the_permalink on a woocommerce product in the cart page will create a link with the attribute selection included in the link such as this:

http://ourdemo.com/product/product-test-2/?attribute_pa_frame=polished-chrome

We want to take these attributes out of the link (for various reasons), however it seems the_permalink, when run on the product id will return them automatically.

Looking at the documentation i cannot seem to find a parameter to not return the attributes? Is there another way to get the base permalink without any parameters?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is that `$_product->get_permalink($cart_item)` automatically adds the attributes to the permalink whenever the product in question is a variation.

I don't understand why you'd want to get rid of that behavior, but it can be accomplished by switching the `$_product->get_permalink()` method to WordPress' default `get_permalink()` function. For non-variation products, the method is just a "wrapper" anyway.

If you aren't showing thumbnails, then you can switch the title link via filter:

```
function so_remove_attributes_from_permalink( $name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ){

    $_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
    if ( ! $_product->is_visible() ){
        $name = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', get_permalink( $cart_item['product_id'] ), $_product->get_title(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
    }

    return $name;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'so_remove_attributes_from_permalink', 10, 3 );
```

If you are showing the thumbnails in the cart, then I think you will need to override the `cart/cart.php` template and modify the references

`$_product->get_permalink( $cart_item )`

to

`get_permalink( $cart_item['product_id'] )`

Comment: Hey @helgatheviking .. I have read your last tutorial on your site and after that following your woocommerce answer :)  Another great answer !

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner thanks! I keep meaning to write more on my site, but I never know what to write about. :)